# Break; issue when correct options are not selected.

Tags: c

I am new and learning to program, I can't get it to "break" properly.
It'supposed to "break" (last if), it the coins are not 0,5,10, or 25. The program is supposed to act like a vending machine, only use dimes, nickels, quarters, and when someone enter "0" it's stops to count the coins.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NICKEL 5
#define DIME 10
#define QUARTER 25

int main(void)
{
int coins;
int sum  = 0;

    printf("Insert Coins: ");
    scanf("%d",&coins);

    while (coins != 0){
    sum += coins;
        if (coins == NICKEL){
            printf("Insert coins: ");
            scanf("%d",&coins);}
        else {continue;}

        if (coins == DIME){
            printf("Insert Coins: ");
            scanf("%d",&coins);}
        else {continue;}

        if (coins == QUARTER){
            printf("Insert Coins: ");
            scanf("%d",&coins);}
        else {continue;}

     if (coins != NICKEL || coins != DIME || coins != QUARTER || coins !=0){
            break;
            printf("wrong coin");}

        printf("the amount you put in: %d",sum);

    }
```

Comment: `coins != NICKEL || coins != DIME || coins != QUARTER || coins != 0` is always true.  Presumably you meant to use `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: Also, when asking questions about incorrect behavior, you usually should state what behavior you expect and what behavior you actually observe.

Comment: what I was trying to do, was for nickel, coins, dime, quarter, and "0", if any other #'s where used than those stated above, would cause the loop to "break" and print our "wrong coin".

Comment: what I am seeing is when I put in a # other than, o,5,10,25 it just goes off in limbo, it doesn't execute or stop.

Comment: Do you understand why using `||` is wrong for that check?  As for the "goes off into limbo" problem, why don't you try running through the program mentally?  Hint: What happens if the first coin is not a nickel? (`continue` perhaps does not mean what you think it does.)

Comment: Note that the `printf()` after a `break;` is dead code — that `printf()` will never be executed.

Comment: if it's always true then it's going to continue to pass the check

Comment: Yeah I don't think this is working how I wanted it, I guess it may work better with a do while statement.

Comment: A `do-while` statement is the same as a `while` statement that iterates at least once.  Changing from one to the other isn't going to magically solve your probems.

Comment: @HBJR try out my answer.

Comment: That's better but when i enter "2" it still goes to limbo, i get a flashing cursor, it should end the program and give a wrong coin message.

Comment: Any recommendations for, if you are having someone input  multiple #'s (int) and you can only use a specific three (5,10,25), and any other than that makes the program terminate? I've tried both If and loops but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Choosing a different type of loop isn't going to fix your logic problems.  I've already explained to you what those problems are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NICKEL 5
#define DIME 10
#define QUARTER 25

int main(void)
{
  int coins;
  int sum  = 0;

  do {
    printf("Insert Coins:");
    scanf("%d", &coins);
    if(coins == NICKEL || coins == DIME || coins == QUARTER) {
      sum += coins;
    } else if(coins == 0) {
      break;
    } else {
      printf("Wrong Coin\n");
    }
  }while(1); // Infinite Loop.

  printf("The amount you put in %d\n", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your in while statement not in break.

> 0 == 0 **true** 0 != 0 **false**

in a control statement (like if-else,for,while) in the condition checking it always evaluate the condition and based on the result, it takes the decision ,

you have written `while (coins != 0)`  when some one enters 0 than it becomes `while (0 != 0)` after evaluating this `while (0)` and that causes the loop to terminate

Comment: Well, there's the other major problem that the `continue` statements cause the loop to prematurely re-iterate when it's not supposed to.